# Source address of TCP_RST segment sent by IPTables

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, ip, iptables

Iptables can be configured to reject a packet with an action such as sending TCP_RST or ICMP_HOST_UNREACHABLE packets back to the source. Like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

What address does IPTables use as the "srcIp" of the TCP_RST segment it sends back to the host? Is it the "destIp" of the packet it received? Or, is it the Ip address configured on the interface from which the packet was received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INPUT` table affects only those packets whose destIp is "owned" by the host.  Since the sender is expecting a response from the destIp, the `TCP_RST` will be returned with the original destIp as its srcIp.  If the `TCP_RST` were returned from any other address, the original sender wouldn't recognize it as a reply to the packet it had transmitted.